# How to make a image full screen in css?

Tags: html, css, layout

I have a image list in html, I am simply trying to make the images full screen however it turned out that the images are full screen but they don't align to the very left of html. The grey is my image.[image]

```
<div id="pictures">
<ul class="img-list">
    <li>
      <a>
        <img src="images/abc/header.png"/>
      </a>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

in css

```
body{
  width:1200px;
  margin:0 auto;
}

ul.img-list {
  list-style-type: none;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}

#pictures{
  width:1200px;
  margin:0 auto;
}
```

Comment: and how you want it to be aligned ?

Comment: you can use ` width:100% and height:100vh;` it's working fine i things

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking why you have space in the left (and actually even in top).. It's due to:

  The default padding of the ul tag.

  The default margin top down of the ul tag.

  The body has an extra margin by default (you're setting it to default for the right left).

I advise you to use something like Normalize.css or in a stricter way use the global selector (*) to delete all extra margins and paddings you maybe don't want them to exist

Comment: I assume it inherits the parent position element. Yeah for me I would like to have the rest of the page confined to 1200px, is there a good way to escape from the ul width?

Comment: Sorry I don't get your request, can you please be more clear ?

Answer (score 0):

You have padding and margin on the ul, I Also changed `width: 1200px;` to `width: 100%` on `#pictures` and `body`.

Try using:

**CSS:**

```
body {
width:100%;
margin:0 auto;
}

ul.img-list {
    list-style-type: none;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

#pictures{
    width:100%;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="pictures">
<ul class="img-list">
    <li>
      <a>
        <img src="http://animals.sandiegozoo.org/sites/default/files/2016-09/animals_hero_lions_0.jpg"/>
      </a>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
```